# Legend Color and Plot Line Color Mismatch

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, mismatch

Hello Overstack Community,

I am a beginner in Python and I am having trouble getting the color of my plot aligned with those of the plot.

Please find below the code I have written:-

```
merged_genres_mmd_plot.pivot_table(index='release_year', columns='genres', aggfunc='count').plot(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Popularity of Genre over the Years', fontsize=18)
plt.legend(['Action','Comedy','Drama','Horror','Western'])
plt.xlabel('Release Year',labelpad = 25)
plt.show()
```

[This is the plot I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6pQr.png)

Can someone help me figure out a way I can align the colors of the legend with that of the plot?

Thanking you in Advance!

Comment: Doesn't it just work if you leave out the `plt.legend()` call?

Comment: Hi,  I need to custom set the legend because I am using a pivot table, and "names" of the other column distorts the legend. I get something like  ---revenue,Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several answers to your question, the best one I think is:

with the data you have you can select what is the x and y axis, using pl.plot() you can plot all the of the curves you have and define it's label, as such:

```
plt.plot(x, y, label = 'Action')
plt.plot(x, y, label = 'Comedy')
.
.
.
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, Not the ideal way I want to do it but it works. Ideally, my code would have been much succinct with the pivot_table.plot(). Thank you so much !